# Default localization XML file in different Culture

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-boilerplate

We are currently using ASP.NET ZERO (ABP). Throughout the course of implementation the XML files with *LocalizedTexts* got bigger and bigger.

To manage *LocalizedTexts* we are using a build-in manager:

[image: Manager]

We use XML (file.xml) file with culture **"en"** and the *LocalizedTexts* are being added there.
There are also other XML files with other cultures like **"de"** (file-de.xml) where some keys are added but some don't.

Problem occures when the site's language is set to **"de"**, then the manager fetches all keys from **"de"** file (file-de.xml) and ultimately there is no way to apply translations to those *LocalizedTexts* which keys are in **"en"** (file.xml) but not in **"de"** (file-de.xml).

Is there a neat way to access all keys in the manager without adding them to multiple files simultanously?

I know we can fetch both and do a union:

```
var allDefaultStrings = source.GetAllStrings(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
var allStrings = source.GetAllStrings();
var union = allStrings.Union(allDefaultStrings, new LocalizedStringComparer());
```